# CMake for C#, how to set OutputType to WinExe?

Tags: c#, cmake

I have a CMake project with C# and C++ targets.

The C# is similar to this example here: https://github.com/bemehiser/cmake_csharp_example

If you change the .net framework to 4.8 by adding this before the WPF executable is added:

```
set(CMAKE_DOTNET_SDK “Microsoft.NET.Sdk”)
set(CMAKE_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK “net48”)
```

Then the OutputType changes to “Exe”.
In Visual Studio this is a Console Application.

I need OutputType to be WinExe instead. How do I achieve this?

Adding this:
`SET_PROPERTY(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_OutputType “WinExe”)` 
Doesn’t help. It adds a second entry to the project.
Adding WIN32 to add_executable doesn’t help either.

How should I fix this?

If I would be able to set properties of the proprty group Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" then I would be able to successfully overwrite it. I don't know of any way to do that with CMake.

Thanks!

I tried going back to the demo project and noticed that there it changes when the .net framework version changes.
I tried setting global proberties.
I tried adding WIN32 to the add_executable command.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this issue was fixed in a nightly build.
I was on 3.26.3 and now I'm on cmake version 3.26.20230508-g71599e2

You also need to add the Win32 flag to the add_executable command.
This did not work in 3.26.3